# При режиме записи 'w' данные некорректно записываются в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboardhook

### Режим записи 'a'

Код:

```
def print_pressed_keys(e):
    with open('key_records.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(f'{e.name, e.scan_code, e.event_type, }\n')
                 
             
        
keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
keyboard.wait('Ctrl+Shift')
```

Ввод:mmmmmmmmmqqqqqq

В файле:

```
('m', 50, 'down')
('m', 50, 'up')
('m', 50, 'down')
('m', 50, 'up')
('m', 50, 'down')
('m', 50, 'up')
```

и т.д.

### Режим записи 'w'

Код:

```
def print_pressed_keys(e):
   with open('key_records.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       f.write(f'{e.name, e.scan_code, e.event_type, }\n')

   keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
   keyboard.wait('Ctrl+Shift')
```

Ввод:qwqwqwa

В файле ('a', 30, 'up')**

#### Почему так происходит?

P.S
Windows 7

Comment: отформатируйте код, у вас все отступы поехали

Comment: функция вызывается на каждый символ, и файл начинает писаться с начала - так и должно быть

Comment: Что именно вы считаете здесь некорректным? Какой результат вы ожидали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При открытии файла в режиме `'w'` создается новый файл или очищается существующий. Поэтому каждый раз когда вы нажимаете на кнопку у вас старое содержимое стирается, после закрытия файла остается информация только о последнем нажатии.

Подробнее см.:

- [Файлы. Работа с файлами.](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/fajly-rabota-s-fajlami.html)
- [Работа с файлами в Python](http://pythonicway.com/python-fileio)